# Why is a collection of non-interacting bosons pathological?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, bose-einstein-condensate, bosons, quantum-statistics

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVppkHxKkek&t=422s) lecture titled "Disorder and Interactions: From Spin Chains to Cold Atoms" the speaker Thierry Giamarchi claims that a collection of non-interacting bosons is totally pathological. His argues it as follows (around 5.43 minutes of the lecture):

> If you take free bosons they fall into the deepest well of the potential. When one boson occupies that well, all the other occupies the same well. So one gets a macroscopic number of bosons in a finite region of space.

First of all the bosons don't fall into the deepest well; it's a classical argument. Bosons occupy the quantum mechanical ground state. I don't see any problem with that. Can someone explain what the author might have in mind or point out a better way of explaining why a collection of free bosons in pathological?

Comment: the temerature of condensation $T_c \sim n^{ \alpha}$, so if $n=N/V \rightarrow \infty$ and we have infinite number of particles per unit volume ("a macroscopic number of bosons in a finite region of space"). Maybe it's pathological, because this infinite number is at any finite temperature below the condensation point $T_c$ and do not give an increase in pressure

Answer (score 1):

His statement (at about 6:08) is that one should treat only interacting bosons "if you want to have a non-pathological thermodynamic limit." The key is the phrase thermodynamic limit. In the thermodynamic limit, we take particle number $N\rightarrow \infty$ at constant density $N/V\rightarrow \text{const}$. It is this limit that is ill-defined for free bosons.

Answer (score 0):

He likely means that for strictly non-interacting bosons the number occupying the same state can be infinite.

Comment: And why is this *pathological*?

Comment: An infinite occupation number is a clear sign that something is wrong.

Comment: @my2cts It is thermodynamically large. How is it infinite?